# "Buff" out an extraneous tag ([buffers] -> [buffer])

Tags: support, retag-request

I think [buffers](/questions/tagged/buffers) which has 55 questions should be a merged or made synonymous with [buffer](/questions/tagged/buffer) (as you see fit), which has 897.

The tag seems to be used to speak about a buffer in general terms, or deals with using multiple buffers in text editors.  I think the [buffer](/questions/tagged/buffer) tag covers both of those cases, and the context of the question can dictate whether it's a single buffer or multiple ones.

Comment: Watch out for questions also tagged with a variation on "protocol" -- they're probably about "Protocol Buffers", a wonderful thing with a horrible name and a separate tag, [tag:protocol-buffers].